# How can i get md5sum for all files inside zip without extracting

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, md5sum

Is there any way to get md5sum for all/anyone file inside zip without extracting the zip?

I can extract needed files using unzip <.zip>

But i need to get md5sum without extracting the zip.

Comment: Show your research effort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but it will get you closer. You wouldn't be extracting the entire zip but extracting a file to pipe it to md5sum to get checksum. Without reading the contents of the file, md5sum won't be able to generate a hash.

Let's say you have 3 files with this MD5:

```
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  a.txt
591785b794601e212b260e25925636fd  b.txt
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  c.txt
```

You zip them into a single file using `zip final.zip a.txt b.txt c.txt`

When you list the files, you see there are 3 files.

```
unzip -l final.zip
Archive:  final.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        6  2021-08-08 17:20   a.txt
        6  2021-08-08 17:20   b.txt
       12  2021-08-08 17:20   c.txt
---------                     -------
       24                     3 files
```

To get MD5 of each of the files without extracting the entire zip, you can do this:

```
unzip -p final.zip a.txt | md5sum
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  -

unzip -p final.zip b.txt | md5sum
591785b794601e212b260e25925636fd  -

unzip -p final.zip c.txt | md5sum
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  -
```

## Alternative

You can do `md5sum *.txt > checksums` to get hash of all files and store them in a checksums file. Add that to the zip so you know the md5 of each of the file when the files were added to zipped.

Comment: Thank you very much, this what i expected. it works charm :)

Comment: @arunkumarA awesome. Feel free to mark this as an accepted answer. You can do that by clicking on a check mark by the answer. I see that you have asked another question. If one of the answer to that other question is suitable, you can mark it as accepted for that question also.

Answer (score 0):

For all files in a zip you can use this;

```
File='final.zip' ; unzip -lqq $File | while read L ; do unzip -p $File ${L##*[[:space:]]} | md5sum | sed "s/-/${L##*[[:space:]]}/" ; done
```

Gives;

```
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  a.txt
591785b794601e212b260e25925636fd  b.txt
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  c.txt
```

Comment: You can use `unzip -Z1 "$File" | grep -v '/$'` instead of `unzip -lqq` as shown in [this answer + comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128303/how-to-list-files-in-a-zip-without-extra-information-in-command-line/128304#comment1098849_128304), then you don't need to regex away the file sizes (the `| grep -v '/$'` removes directories since those cannot be `md5sum`ed). Also, always use quoting (like `$File`) to make sure it works even if the file name contains spaces. Finally, the `sed` expression doesn't work when the zip contains nested folders and thus a `/` (too many slashes).

Comment: I've [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703085/how-can-i-get-md5sum-for-all-files-inside-zip-without-extracting/75349692#75349692) that fixes these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MartinMann's answer, a version that works correctly no matter if the file names contain spaces or special characters:

```bash
ZIPFILE="final.zip"; unzip -Z1 "$ZIPFILE" | grep -v '/$' | while read line; do echo "$(unzip -p "$ZIPFILE" "$line" | md5sum | cut '-d ' -f1)  $L" ; done
```

Gives:

```
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  a.txt
591785b794601e212b260e25925636fd  b.txt
6f5902ac237024bdd0c176cb93063dc4  path/to/file with spaces.txt
```

Comment: Seems that you may have missed `echo` (or `print` or equivalent) between the `do ` and `"$(unzip -p "`.